# How to make sure that each Spark DataFrame partition does not exceed given size(MB) of data

Tags: apache-spark

In one of spark dataframe operation I found that size(MB) of input for each task varies significantly. Some task has size almost 1GB while other has 15MB. Higher input size is causing executor lost.

I know that tweaking **spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead** will make it work at some point. But I want to know, is there any way I can repartition DataFrame so that size of each partition does not exceed given size(MB).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specifically ensure the *partitions themselves* are sized properly. It is a *partiion-time* task not *runtime/task execution time*. The options are:

- Increase the number of partitions. This is a blunt instrument / brute force approach: you will end up with many more partitions then you want - even if this were even feasible given whatever your input source may be. But processing many extra partitions is actually not all *that* bad. It adds a fractional additional time to the processing.
- *Better approach*.  Think carefully about how the data is partitioned and possibly improve on it to avoid the skew. This may involve an additional processing step to repartition or change the grouping.

Once again this is not fixable *only at task execution time*: it requires a re-working of the data distributiion - as it is presented to the Spark scheduler in the form of the partitions it uses to send to the workers.